# how to connect from powershell to powershell of another environment

Tags: powershell

i am runing powershell and from my powershell i want to connect to my Exchange powershell,
the diffrance betwwen the two files is in their target(right click =proproties),

"normal" powershell target =**"%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"**

"exchange" powershell target = **"C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -PSConsoleFile "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\bin\exshell.psc1" -noexit -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\bin\Exchange.ps1'""**

is there a way to connect to the exchange powershell by code??, my guess is to add those two extra line like in the target...

Answer (score 2):

That command line will only work if the Exchange management tools are installed (it's going to try to load the Exchange management snapin.

Generally, it's easier to use implicit remoting in a script and import the functions from the remote shell into your current session:

http://www.mikepfeiffer.net/2010/02/managing-exchange-2010-with-remote-powershell/

Comment: thanks, that looks very nice but unfortunately i am using Exchange 2007. :(

Comment: Then I think you'll need to install the management tools and load that snapin in your session.

Comment: The Exchange Management Tools that come with Exchange.